# What is the best way to check if the value inside an option inside a result satisfies a condition in rust?

Tags: rust, option-type

I have a function that returns something like `Result<Option<Value>, Error>`, and I want to check if there is a value and if it matches a condition. There are two straightforward ways:

```rust
if let Ok(Some(value)) = func() {
    if /* condition */ {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

and

```rust
if func().is_ok_and(|option| option.is_some_and(|value| /* condition */ )) {
    /* do something */
}
```

The first one seems more readable to me, but in some cases I can imagine a lot of nesting showing up. The second is less readable and introduces extremely long lines, but prevents excessive nesting. Is one preferable over the other? Or is there some other way I'm unaware of that is simpler?

Something similar to what is discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/929) would be very helpful, by doing this:

```rust
if let Ok(Some(value)) = func() && /* condition */ {
    /* do something */
}
```

preventing excessive nesting and staying readable, but I found no equivalent of this that currently exists in rust.

Comment: You can get an `Option<T>` from a `Result<Option<T>, _>` with `res.ok().flatten()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std` provides a `matches!` macro, which you can use (it expands to a `match` statement, so you can use the `if` syntax):

```
if matches!(func, Ok(Some(value)) if /* condition */) {
    /* do something */
}
```

`matches!` is the best choice when you need a boolean and not a branch, but still works inside an `if`, too.

Comment: This doesn't help in case of big nesting, which IIRC is mainly what OP is worried about.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: The OP may fear nesting, but at the same time seems okay with using if-let-chain which doesn't handle nesting either. `matches!` is a tad more verbose than an if-let-chain, but not that much.

Answer (score 6):

A pretty clean way of doing it without somewhat abusing the methods on `Result` and `Option` is to just `match`:

```rs
match value {
    Ok(Some(x)) if /* condition */ => { /* do something */ },
    _ => {}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help in case of big nesting, which IIRC is mainly what OP is worried about.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use nightly, you can use the `&&` version, [it is just unstable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667):

```rust
#![feature(let_chains)]

if let Ok(Some(value)) = func() && /* condition */ {
    /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the nesting by inverting the condition. Combined with [breaking from block](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2046-label-break-value.html), this can be pretty readable even in case of many nested conditions:

```rust
'do_work: {
    let Ok(Some(value)) = func() else { break 'do_work };
    if !/* condition */ { break 'do_work; }
    
    // do something
}
```